# setTimeout with or without anonymous function? What's the difference?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I used this code (followed by an xmlhttprequest that fills the "tcap" textarea):

```
st=setTimeout(checkme(),4000)
```

where `checkme()` is:

```
function checkme() {
    if (typeof (st) != 'undefined') clearTimeout(st)
    if (document.getElementById("tcap").innerHTML.length > 0) {
        document.getElementById('waitmsg').style.display = 'none'
    } else {
        st = setTimeout(checkme(), 1000)
    }
}
```

If I run it, it **freezes Firefox 19** with no error message.
But if I replace the first argument (both in code and in the checkme() function) with:

```
st=setTimeout(function(){checkme()},4000)
```

it works correctly.
So my question is: what's the difference in calling the `checkme()` function with or without the anon function? Why in the first case it freezes Firefox?

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

You need to remove the parens in

```
st=setTimeout(checkme(),4000)
```

so instead:

```
st=setTimeout(checkme,4000)
```

otherwise, the function is invoked right away.

Since you have the same error inside the checkme function, it probably kills your browser due to unbounded recursion.

Answer (score 5):

`setTimeout` accepts a function as an argument, and the correct way to pass a function as an argument is either defining it as an anonymous function, or just providing the function name. If you use parenthesis(brackets), you aren't actually passing a function: You are executing the function and passing the result of the function to setTimeout.

Hence, when specifying a function in setTimeout, and anywhere else you need to pass a function as an argument, you should not use parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using the parenthesis within the setTimeout function.  You should only be passing in a reference to the method.  What you are doing is invoking the method and passing the return value in to the set timeout method.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `setTimeout(checkme(),4000)`, you are passing the return value of checkme();
But if you want to pass it as a function you need to do in following ways

```
setTimeout(function(){checkme()},4000)
```

or

```
st=setTimeout(checkme,4000)
```